# One remote switch two lighting circuits

Tags: lighting, ceiling, remote-control

As installed by an electrician, after working well for a time, when the remote (wall-mounted) switch is now operated, one circuit goes live and the other switches off. So one group of lights must always be on. How can I get both light sets to resync?

Comment: We're going to need a _lot_ more info to be able to help you. Make/model of the remote. If you are comfortable, turn off the breaker, take the cover plate(s) off the switch(es) in question, remove the switch from the wall, _do NOT disconnect any wiring_, and get us clear, focused pics of how the switches are wired and how the wires group into cables as they go into the box - including where ever the remote's receiver is wired into the circuit.

Comment: Yes, electronic/smart devices are *not nearly* standard enough to guess at what could be going on there.  Old-school 3-way switches are pretty standard, and improper installation would cause such a problem from the moment it was installed.  These older switches do not reconfigure themselves *all on their own*.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote switch" in this case?